# Проблема с выводом свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

Тренируюсь. Почему не выводится "Большой"? Возможно не до конца понял систему *this*.

```js
var obj = {
  size: 'Большой',
  value: this.size
};
var write = obj.value;
console.log(write);
```

Comment: плохо тренируешсья this берет всегда сверху запомни

Comment: имя переменной `write` "плохое".

Comment: Что значит "сверху"? В моём примере свойство к которому обращаюсь через this ведь всерху находится.

Answer (score 0):

`this` - в данном случает относится к глобальной области видимости. А глобально эта переменная не определена, если определим, то получим вывод.

```js
size = 100;
var obj = {
  size: 'Большой',
  value: this.size
};
var write = obj.value;
console.log(write);

//  другой вариант

function Person(size){
  this.size = size || 'big'
  this.value = this.size
}

var person = new Person('small')
console.log(person.value, person.size);
```

- можно начать [с этого](https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures)
- [продолжить](https://javascript.ru/object/prototype) и [далее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: Попробовал Ваш пример. По-прежнему undefined

Comment: нажмите кнопку выполнить код...